# Complex merge of data relations

Tags: optimization, haskell, graph, set, relation

Let's say that I have a set of relations that looks like this:

```
relations :: [(A, B)]
instance Monoid A
instance Monoid B
```

I want to transform this set of relations to a new set of relations of `A`s and `B`s.

Now, here comes the tricky stuff:

1. `A`s that are equal should have their `B`s `mappend`ed.
2. `B`s that are equal should have their `A`s `mappend`ed.
3. Repeat until all `A`s and `B`s are distinct (Or don't, depending on if this can be done non-iteratively somehow).

**EDIT: The ordering constraint made the problem trivial, so I removed it.**

One can assume that `Ord`, `Hashable`, or whatever else you need is available. For all intents and purposes, one could say that `A` behaves *exactly* like `HashSet` and `B` behaves *exactly* like `Vector` (or some other type with reasonable size checking).

This means that one can assume that `let s = size (mappend a b); s >= size a; s >= size b`, and that `a, b :: B; mappend a b /= mappend b a <=> a, b not mempty; a > b => (mappend a c) > b`, etc.

An example of how this transformation would happen (Pretend that `<a, b>` is `Set.fromList [a, b]`)

```
[(<1>, [a]), (<4>, [d]), (<2>, [b]), (<5>, [e]), (<1>, [b]), (<2>, [a]), (<3>, [c])]
-- Merge `A`s for equal `B`s
[(<1,2>, [a]), (<4>, [d]), (<1,2> [b]), (<5>, [e]), (<3>, [c])]
-- Merge `B`s for equal `A`s
[(<1,2>, [a, b]), (<4>, [d]), (<5>, [e]), (<3>, [c])]
-- All values are distinct, so we're done.
```

How can this be done in an as efficient manner as possible (time, space)?

Comment: So `B` is treated as set with significant order when you do the equality check, correct? i.e. `[1,2] /= [2,1]`

Comment: @jberryman, for my specific situation, that does not matter (Because all `B`s are sorted when appended, kinda) but for this question to be useful to others, it might be best to just say that there's an `instance Eq B` and leave it at that.

Comment: The order (1.) and (2.) in your procedure matters -- different order of applying those rules leads to different results.  Is that how it is supposed to work?  I cannot see any shortcut to try applying (1.) then (2.) then (1.) then (2.) ... until neither rule can apply.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz, yes, I doubted that it was possible without a predefined ordering of operations; I just thought that it might be possible to reduce the set of merge candidates on each round, thus making the algorithm recursive rather than iterative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general case cannot be done any better than the straightforward way with an O(n^2) merge, so the total algorithm could be O(n^3). Without restrictions on the order of elements in the list and results of `mappend`, you have to match each pair of elements to see whether they should be merged, and repeat until done.

```
merge :: Eq e => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> e) -> [a] -> (Bool,[a])
merge combine eqval [] = (False, [])
merge combine eqval (x:xs) = (not (null a) || t, y : zs)
  where
    e = eqval x
    (a,b) = partition ((e ==) . eqval) xs
    y = mconcat (x:a)
    (t,zs) = merge combine eqval b

mergeRelations :: [(A,B)] -> [(A,B)]
mergeRelations = go False
  where
    mergeFsts = merge (\(a1,b1) (a2,b2) -> (a1, b1 `mappend` b2)) fst
    mergeSnds = merge (\(a1,b1) (a2,b2) -> (a1 `mappend` a2, b1)) snd
    go started xs
      | started && not f = xs
      | s = go True n
      | otherwise = m
        where
          (f,m) = mergeFsts xs
          (s,n) = mergeSnds m
```

Comment: How would this change if the ordering constraint was removed, then? Meaning that the relations are unordered, and that `mappend a b /= mappend b a` when `a /= b`. `Ord`, `Hashable` etc. would of course be available.

Comment: Miscommunication, I'm afraid. I meant that given some restrictions like: the `A`s are always sorted, `mappend`ing behaves well with respect to order; there _might_ be a better way, without such, I'm almost sure there isn't.

Comment: I've removed the ordering constraint and added some details that make the problem less trivial but open to better algorithms. See the question for details.